# Trying to crawl a site

Tags: seo

I'm trying to crawl a site, I've tried using Screaming Frog and https://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/seo-tools/google-sitemap-generator/ and both return the same results when I try a crawl.  It finds the home page, but it then will give 404's for all the links it finds on the page.  If I got to the site manually I don't get 404's.

I'm new to Craft CMS so I don't know much (yet).  Inherited this site not too long ago.

Site is: https://highparknaturecentre.com/

In addition, I also noticed that If I go to https://highparknaturecentre.com/about the server returns http status 404 but returns the body content.  Could this be a server issue?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah the server is probably misconfigured. Craft relies on a 404 happening to do some of what it does, but the status code should be changed before the response is returned.

I don't have enough information to tell you how it is misconfigured. Would depend on the webserver (Nginx/Apache/whatever) and we'd need to see the specific config.

There also is no `/sitemap.xml` on the site.